# Does pega have some keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: pega

I was looking for a way in which we could save, check in, delete, run, search a rule, navigate the app explorer. I tried to find it on pdn but those links are of a previous version of pega.

Comment: for which pega version?

Comment: I am talking about Pega 7

Answer (score 3):

Pega's PDN includes documentation about [keyboard shorcuts (hotkeys)](https://pdn.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v71/procomhelpmain.htm#definitions/s/shortcut.htm) provided since Pega 7.1 version in order to enable faster development.

Here follows a comprehensive list of available hotkeys.

### Ruleform Actions

```
New              CTRL + ALT + N
Save             CTRL + S
Check In \ Check Out \ Private Edit   CTRL + ALT + F
Discard \ Delete                      CTRL + ALT + D
Copy \ Save As   CTRL + ALT + C
View XML         CTRL + ALT + X
View Java        CTRL + ALT + J
View References  CTRL + ALT + I
View Siblings    CTRL + ALT + O
Run              CTRL + ALT + R
Preview          CTRL + ALT + P
Refresh          CTRL + ALT + L
Close            CTRL + ALT + W
Help             CTRL + ALT + H
```

### Debug actions

```
Tracer          CTRL + ALT + T
Clipboard       CTRL + ALT + B
UI Inspector    CTRL + ALT + U
Performance     CTRL + ALT + G
Alerts          CTRL + ALT + A
```

### General

```
PRPC Help               CTRL + `
Expand Left Pane        SHIFT + RIGHT ARROW
Collapse Left Pane      SHIFT + LEFT ARROW
Go Home                 CTRL + ALT + HOME
Log Off                 CTRL + ALT + END
Operator Preferences    CTRL + ALT + K
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Pega 7 Help (from Resources button on the upper right near the user menu) and search for shortcuts. You should find in the results *Shortcut - definition*. There you will find more information regarding shortcuts based on three categories: Basic, Forms and Tools.

Just for the examples you mentioned:

```
Save record currently in focus     CTRL + S
Check In, Check Out, Private Edit  CTRL + ALT + F
Discard/Delete                     CTRL + ALT + D
Actions > Run                      CTRL + ALT + R
```

Comment: When I performed the above stated steps I found this [page](https://pdn.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v63sp1/Default.htm#definitions/s/shortcut.htm). And as I am using pega 7 the step `Select Preferences from the Designer Studio profile menu to extend or override the default keyboard shortcuts` cannot be performed as no option to override the default keyboard shortcuts was found from the prefence menu, only default application skin can be seen

Comment: I was getting to [this page](https://pdn.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v63sp1/Default.htm#basics/v6portal/v6keyboardshortcuts.htm)

Answer (score 0):

These are the shortcuts I know of:

```
ALT+CTRL+B - CLIPBOARD
ALT+CTRL+T - TRACER
ALT+CTRL+W - CLOSE CURRENT TAB
ALT+CTRL+F - CHECKOUT/CHECK-IN
ALT+CTRL+C - NEW-RULE
CTRL+S - SAVE
ALT+CTRL+A - ALERTS
ALT+CTRL+K - OPERATOR PREFERENCES
ALT+CTRL+U - LIVE UI
ALT+CTRL+R - RUN
ALT+CTRL+X - XML VIEW
ALT+CTRL+G - PERFORMANCE
ALT+CTRL+L - Tab REFRESH
```